# Javascript Date Parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a JSON service providing me with minutes. I then wish to convert these minutes into a DD:HH:MM format. [Days, Hours, Minutes]

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me how to accomplish this?

Thanks Devin

Comment: What format are you getting the "minutes" in?

Comment: Hi Guys. I am literally getting minutes back. So 5467 minutes. Is there a native method to get that into DD:HH:MM, other than writing my own?

Comment: There are 60 minutes in an hour and there are 24 hours in a day. Do we need to write a statement for you to break number of minutes into number of days/hours/minutes? It is 3rd year school maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common function that removes a number as high as possible, and then continues again with the remainder: http://jsfiddle.net/sL43t/1/.

```
var arr = [];
var value = 5467;

var gain = function(minutes) {
    var amount = Math.floor(value / minutes);
    arr.push(amount < 10 ? "0" + amount : amount);  // add zero padding if needed
    value %= minutes;
};

gain(24 * 60);  // minutes per day
gain(60);       // minutes per hour
gain(1);        // minutes per minute

var str = arr.join(":");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert minutes into days, hours and minutes using something like:

```
// Helper
function z(n) {
  return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
}

var n = 5467;
var days = n / 1440 | 0;
var hours = n % 1440 / 60 | 0;
var mins = n % 60;

alert( z(days) + ':' + z(hours) + ':' + z(mins) ); // 03:19:07
```

Comment: this is also very nice as is separates the parts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = 123456; // the given minutes

var days = Math.floor(t / (60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((t - days * 60 * 24) / 60);
var mintues = t - days * 60 * 24 - hours * 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming obj.totalMin to be total minutes
var obj = {
    totalMin : 4859
}

var days = Math.floor( obj.totalMin / (60 * 24));          
var hours = Math.floor( obj.totalMin / 60) - (days * 24);          
var minutes = obj.totalMin % 60;

document.write (days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes);

​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vt6hZ/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your own function for this you can convert your number to milliseconds and use that to create a date object. Then output that date object using whatever format you choose to.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        var totalMinutes = ;
        var days = totalMinutes/1440;
        var totalHours = totalMinutes%1440;
        var hours = totalHours/60;
        var minutes = totalHours%60;
        alert("DD:"+days+" HH:"+hours+" MM:"+minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you found your answer, but just throwing this out there because it seems easier to me, maybe help someone else:

```
function makeTime(v, lead) {
    v = parseInt(v); // ensures variable is an integer to do math too
    var days = Math.floor(v/1440),
        hrs = Math.floor(v/60 - (days*24)),
        mins = xmins % 60;
    var ret = {
        days: lead ? "" + (days < 10 ? "0" + days : days) : days,
        hrs: lead ? "" + (hrs < 10 ? "0" + hrs : hrs) : hrs,
        mins: lead ? "" + (mins < 10 ? "0" + mins : mins) : mins
    };
    ret.combo = ret.days + ":" + ret.hrs + ":" + ret.mins;
    return ret;
}

var xmins = 11404; // ou can se your data or whatever, this is just an example of minutes
var breakDown = makeTime(xmins); // this will return pure integers on each value
    //  OR!!
var breakDown = makeTime(xmins, true); // the true parameter just simply decides if you want leading variable, and string on each

// use

$("#eleID").text(breakDown.combo);
```

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks for the contribution.